# Web Service background worker?

Tags: .net, multithreading, queue, backgroundworker

I have a Windows Service which will check db every 20 mins, if there're new records. It will send it to a web service to store to another db.

Everything work fine but I want to improve sending speed. I intend to use queue in webservice to store record WS send to and there's will be a method run behind to check that queue and save record in queue to db.

Is the any way for me to do that ? Tks

Comment: This question is pretty vague. I think it would help if you gave more details. How many records are we talking about? How long does it take to send them? What exactly are you having trouble on with the queue?

Comment: The db of WS is increasing overtime. Now the DB had more than 10 mil record. The ws, webservice is done but I want to improve its performance by increasing Sending Speed by use Queue in Web Service. The web service will receive record sent from WS and store to queue and let the other process to handle that queue